# Looping through an Object which contatain Arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to loop trough object which contains two or more objects, every of that objects have one or more arrays of objects.

Goal is: To loop over every of that arrays and based on `timeNeededForMakingAssignment` return that object into new array.

Here is how objects structure looks: 
[image]

here is how that object looks trough json:

```
TABLE DATA: {  
   "COMP_01":{  
      "prop":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"24",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",

         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",

         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"19",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"asinger@churchmutual.com",
         }
      ],
      "wc":[  
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"24",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"asinger@churchmutual.com",
         }
      ],
      "lb":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
          {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
      ],
       "auto":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
          {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
      ],
    }
    "COMP_02": {  
      "prop":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"24",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",

         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",

         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"19",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "username":"asinger@churchmutual.com",
         }
      ],
      "wc":[  
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"lneumann@churchmutual.com",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"24",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
            "tpaRequired":false,
            "username":"asinger@churchmutual.com",
         }
      ],
      "lb":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
          {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
      ],
       "auto":[  
         {  

            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"23",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
         {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
          {  
            "timeNeededForMakingAssignment":"22",
            "timeReceived":"12:00",
         },
      ],
    }
}
```

How to loop through this object and return object based pn property `timeNeededForMakingAssignment`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood well your request but i think it might be something like this:

```
var comp=tableData.COMP_01;
var prop=comp.prop;
prop.forEach(function(e){
    if(e.timeNeededForMakingAssignement==="25"){
        //Do your stuff here
    }
});

//Repeat for COMP_02
```

I also think you should set this value as an int, not a string

Comment: HI @Bibimission I think your logic is good, but I get error regaring forEach: 
"Uncaught TypeError: tableData.forEach is not a function"

Comment: Proubably I need someting intead of forEach which can loop trough object, right?

Comment: Well, I thought tableData was an Array but it's not. You can't iterate with your comp_01 comp_02.

Comment: Maybe I can convert this object to array and then user your logic ?